# How to find characters causing encoding failure

Tags: iphone, encoding

I am grabbing a string through a http request. The string is Big 5 with ANSI color encoding.

If I just run a:

```
NSStringEncoding big5 = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingBig5);
NSString *httpResponse2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:big5];
```

It fails, I believe because of the ANSI colors.

So, I'm iterating over the string and removing any character 27 (esc) followed by 91 ([) until I hit 109 (m). This should get rid of any ANSI formatting. It works with some strings, but with a long enough string I get a problem. The encoding fails and since iPhone encoding silently fails and returns nil, I'm having trouble finding what character is responsible for this. Is there any way I can find out which character is causing my encoding to fail?